# PyTorch AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'size'

Tags: python, transformer-model, class-transformer

I'm building two parallel convolutional neural networks (CNN) in parallel with a Transformer encoder network to classify image data. I'm working on a dataset of faces to classify emotions from one of 7 classes.
But when I ran the model, I got this error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'size'.
> The model is as follows:

```
class parallel_all_you_want(nn.Module):
    # Define all layers present in the network
    def __init__(self,num_emotions):
        super().__init__() 
        
        ################ TRANSFORMER BLOCK #############################
        # maxpool the input feature map/tensor to the transformer 
        # a rectangular kernel worked better here for the rectangular input spectrogram feature map/tensor
        self.transformer_maxpool = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=[1,4], stride=[1,4])
        
        transformer_layer = nn.TransformerEncoderLayer(
            d_model=40, # input feature (frequency) dim after maxpooling 40*282 -> 40*70 (MFC*time)
            nhead=4, # 4 self-attention layers in each multi-head self-attention layer in each encoder block
            dim_feedforward=512, # 2 linear layers in each encoder block's feedforward network: dim 40-->512--->40
            dropout=0.4, 
            activation='relu' # ReLU: avoid saturation/tame gradient/reduce compute time
        )
        
        self.transformer_encoder = nn.TransformerEncoder(transformer_layer, num_layers=4)
        
        ############### 1ST PARALLEL 2D CONVOLUTION BLOCK ############
        # 3 sequential conv2D layers: (1,40,282) --> (16, 20, 141) -> (32, 5, 35) -> (64, 1, 8)
        self.conv2Dblock1 = nn.Sequential(
            
            # 1st 2D convolution layer
            nn.Conv2d(
                in_channels=1, # input volume depth == input channel dim == 1
                out_channels=16, # expand output feature map volume's depth to 16
                kernel_size=3, # typical 3*3 stride 1 kernel
                stride=1,
                padding=1
                      ),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(16), # batch normalize the output feature map before activation
            nn.ReLU(), # feature map --> activation map
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2), #typical maxpool kernel size
            nn.Dropout(p=0.3), #randomly zero 30% of 1st layer's output feature map in training
            
            # 2nd 2D convolution layer identical to last except output dim, maxpool kernel
            nn.Conv2d(
                in_channels=16, 
                out_channels=32, # expand output feature map volume's depth to 32
                kernel_size=3,
                stride=1,
                padding=1
                      ),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(32),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=4, stride=4), # increase maxpool kernel for subsequent filters
            nn.Dropout(p=0.3), 
            
            # 3rd 2D convolution layer identical to last except output dim
            nn.Conv2d(
                in_channels=32,
                out_channels=64, # expand output feature map volume's depth to 64
                kernel_size=3,
                stride=1,
                padding=1
                      ),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=4, stride=4),
            nn.Dropout(p=0.3),
        )
        ############### 2ND PARALLEL 2D CONVOLUTION BLOCK ############
        # 3 sequential conv2D layers: (1,40,282) --> (16, 20, 141) -> (32, 5, 35) -> (64, 1, 8)
        self.conv2Dblock2 = nn.Sequential(
            
            # 1st 2D convolution layer
            nn.Conv2d(
                in_channels=1, # input volume depth == input channel dim == 1
                out_channels=16, # expand output feature map volume's depth to 16
                kernel_size=3, # typical 3*3 stride 1 kernel
                stride=1,
                padding=1
                      ),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(16), # batch normalize the output feature map before activation
            nn.ReLU(), # feature map --> activation map
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2), #typical maxpool kernel size
            nn.Dropout(p=0.3), #randomly zero 30% of 1st layer's output feature map in training
            
            # 2nd 2D convolution layer identical to last except output dim, maxpool kernel
            nn.Conv2d(
                in_channels=16, 
                out_channels=32, # expand output feature map volume's depth to 32
                kernel_size=3,
                stride=1,
                padding=1
                      ),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(32),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=4, stride=4), # increase maxpool kernel for subsequent filters
            nn.Dropout(p=0.3), 
            
            # 3rd 2D convolution layer identical to last except output dim
            nn.Conv2d(
                in_channels=32,
                out_channels=64, # expand output feature map volume's depth to 64
                kernel_size=3,
                stride=1,
                padding=1
                      ),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=4, stride=4),
            nn.Dropout(p=0.3),
        )

        self.fc1_linear = nn.Linear(512*2+40,num_emotions) 
        
        self.softmax_out = nn.Softmax(dim=1) # dim==1 is the freq embedding
        
    # define one complete parallel fwd pass of input feature tensor thru 2*conv+1*transformer blocks
    def forward(self,x):
        print(x.shape)
     
        conv2d_embedding1 = self.conv2Dblock1(x) # x == N/batch * channel * freq * time
        
        conv2d_embedding1 = torch.flatten(conv2d_embedding1, start_dim=1) 
        
        conv2d_embedding2 = self.conv2Dblock2(x) # x == N/batch * channel * freq * time
       
        conv2d_embedding2 = torch.flatten(conv2d_embedding2, start_dim=1) 
     
        x_maxpool = self.transformer_maxpool(x)

        x_maxpool_reduced = torch.squeeze(x_maxpool,1)
        
        x = x_maxpool_reduced.permute(2,0,1) 
        
        transformer_output = self.transformer_encoder(x)
      
        transformer_embedding = torch.mean(transformer_output, dim=0) # dim 40x70 --> 40
        
        complete_embedding = torch.cat([conv2d_embedding1, conv2d_embedding2,transformer_embedding], dim=1)  

        output_logits = self.fc1_linear(complete_embedding)  
        
        output_softmax = self.softmax_out(output_logits)
        
        return output_logits, output_softmax
```

This is the implementation of Keras' model.summary method:

```
from torchsummary import summary

# need device to instantiate model
device = 'cuda'

# instantiate model for 8 emotions and move to GPU 
model = parallel_all_you_want(len(emotion_labels)).to(device)

# include input feature map dims in cemotions_dictall to summary()
summary(model, input_size=(1,40,282))
```

Comment: Do you have the full traceback that shows what line this is happening on?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: `in <module>
      8 
      9 # include input feature map dims in cemotions_dictall to summary()
---> 10 summary(model, input_size=(1,40,282))`

Comment: The problem is that the encoder return null. Why i have this problem?